# Adding localstorage array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having hard time on this localstorage array. I have search it here  but can't get it out. Hope you can help me with this one.

Here is my code.

```
$(function(){
    var addWishlist = $('.add-wishlist');
    addWishlist.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var product_ids = [];
        localStorage.setItem('product_ids', $(this).prev().val() );
        console.log( localStorage.getItem('product_ids') );
    });
});
```

The output is:
[image]

The output should be [2, 3, 4, 1]

Comment: What is `$(this).prev().val()`? (Hint: not an array.)

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="{{ $product->id }}" name="product_id">`That is the prev of add to wishlist.

Comment: Everytime I click the wishlist button it will give you a number. That is an i.d.. It should be save in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to array on button click and then store it to local storage. Also `product_ids` should be initialized outside the click event

```
var product_ids = [];
addWishlist.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();      
        product_ids.push($(this).prev().val())
        localStorage.setItem('product_ids',product_ids );
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('product_ids') );
    });
```

Comment: @Rbex did you declare the product_ids outside the button click?

Comment: It works now. Thanks for reminding that one but the output is 2, 3, 4. Can I convert it to array? I'm happy if you can answer it as well but I can search it how. Thanks.

Comment: @Rbex It is already an array anyway. just do a console log and check console.log(product_ids) , mark as answer if it has helped

Comment: You are a rockstar! Thank you so much @Sajeetharan.

Comment: `localStorage` can only store *strings*. If you want to store an array the simplest way is to convert it to/from JSON when you set/get it. If you're going to use a separate array variable as well as local storage then on page load you'll need to populate that array with whatever is currently in local storage, otherwise the code above will delete values from the previous session.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things wrong:

1. The array `product_ids` is always empty because you need to `push()` or `unshift()`, or anything to fill the array.
2. `localStorage` can only take strings, I don't even think it will even recognize your empty array.

#### Changes

1. Added an extra button to load the data into `localStorage`
2. Text is entered then click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button.
3. The value of the text input is `push()`ed into the array `productList`.
4. Each time `productList` is updated, it is stored in a hidden input `#cache`
5. When the <kbd>Done</kbd> button is clicked, the value of `#cache` is converted into a string by `JSON.stringify`.
6. Once `productList` is a string, it is then stored in `localStorage`and is displayed in `#output`.

Due to SO sandbox, the Snippet doesn't work, so review this [<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/xIZJ8PQkPUVK9BAephaB/) instead.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>wishList</legend>
    <input id='in1'>
    <button><a href='#' id='add'>Add</a>
    </button>
    <button><a href='#' id='done'>Done</a>
    </button>
    <label for='out1'>wishList:</label>
    <output id='out1'></output>
    <input id='cache' type='hidden'>
  </fieldset>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var productList = [];
      $('#add').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var productItem = $('#in1').val();
        productList.push(productItem);
        $('#cache').val(productList);
      });
      $('#done').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cached = $('#cache').val();
        var str = JSON.stringify(cached);
        localStorage.setItem('proList', str);
        var stored = localStorage.getItem('proList');
        console.log(stored)
        $('#out1').html(stored);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```